# i want to hide fragment layout when click any place in screen

Tags: android

Here is one frame layout added in bottom view. i want to hide if user click on any place on the screen[image]

i have tried to get parent layout and on that touch listener set visiblity GONE but on touch listner is not working. here my code is.
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

```
    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                // show-hide view here

                contentSubTableList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                AppUtility.showToast(PhoneBaseActivity.this, "On touch listner");

                return true;
            }

            contentSubTableList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            AppUtility.showToast(PhoneBaseActivity.this, "On touch listner");
            return true;
        }
    });

    rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    llParentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llParentView);
    llParentView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                // show-hide view here

                contentSubTableList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                AppUtility.showToast(PhoneBaseActivity.this, "On touch listner");

                return true;
            }


            contentSubTableList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            AppUtility.showToast(PhoneBaseActivity.this, "On touch listner");

            return true;
        }
    });
```

please any one help me in that.

Comment: you can try adding that on your parent layout of your xml

Comment: @VivekMishra yes i have also try add parent layout in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/llParentView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/_50sdp"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/_50sdp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_minus2sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_whitetable" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvTableList"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSubTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

setOnClickListener() on Fragment's Parent View Layout

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method for hide and show fragment

```
public void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment){

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                    android.R.animator.fade_out);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        ft.show(fragment);
        Log.d("hidden","Show");
    } else {
        ft.hide(fragment);
        Log.d("Shown","Hide");                        
    }

    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: lay out not added in specific fragment it is added on activity for common view for all